# TS Linting. Disable forcing private methods to require method documents

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have had a bit of a dig online and I can not seem to find a way to stop TS Linting from showing errors when private methods do not have documents.

I would like to enforce documentation on all public facing methods but not the private ones.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is coming from the [`completed-docs`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/completed-docs/) rule.

You should be able to do:

```
"completed-docs": [true, { "methods": {
  "locations": "instance",
  "privacies": ["public"]
}}]
```

In your `tslint.json` which will override any default rule you might have. Of course, you can update it with more properties since there are a lot of options for required docs.

Worse comes to worst you can do use `// tslint:disable` and the like, but I don't think you should have to do this.

Comment: Perfect thanks I will give it a go quick and accept this if it works